# Wants to go to Message composing screen from My Application

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want Invoke Message composing screen  &  Call from My application.  i have written following code . Please help me for getting into message composing screen ..

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         switch (which) {
         case 0:{
             Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
             callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bean.getPhoneno()));
             startActivity(callIntent);
         }break;
         case 1 :{




         }break;
         }

               }
            });enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends i got one better way for doing this -:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, 
            Uri.fromParts("sms", phone_number, null));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Content of the SMS goes here..."); 
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

or

```
 String number = "12345678";
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null)));
```

Comment: thanks to all for your Answers . I got one more way for doing this -:

Answer (score 1):

To open native SMS composer:

```
String number = "12346556";  // The number on which you want to send SMS
20
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null)));
```

OR

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:12346556");
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
it.putExtra("sms_body", "Here you can set the SMS text to be sent");
startActivity(it);
```

More info: [Sending SMS example](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/android-%E2%80%93-sending-sms-from-android-application-%E2%80%93-method-1/).